# Jenkins Shared failure

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am facing an issue with Jenkins shared library. It is failing with the below error.

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException.collector
    in object org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException@545ac2e4
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@633a4023
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@4fc67d86
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable@398d975c
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@45695fe5
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution.thread
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution@584b34fe
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution$SuccessAdapter.this$0
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution$SuccessAdapter@20f23f9f
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException:org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
```

**Groovy Vars code**

```groovy
import org.com.*

def call(string project, string repo){
    gt = new git(this, project, repo)
    gt.gitclone('pip','ospatchingpipeline' )
    git(this, project)
}
```

**Source class**

```groovy
package org.com.*

/**
 * Created by mishrav on 12/14/2017.
 */
class git implements Serializable {
    def project
    def repo
    git(string project, string repo) {
        this.project = project
        this.repo = repo
    }
    def gitclone(project, repo){
        echo(" cloning ${project}")
        git url: "ssh://git@bitbucket:7999/${project}/${repo}.git"
    }
}
```

**Pipeline code**

```groovy
@Library('pipelineLibrary') _
import java.util.regex.Pattern
//def lib = library("pipelineLibrary").com.clsa.scm.git()
//library identifier: 'pipelineLibrary@master', retriever: modernSCM([$class: 'GitSCMSource',remote: 'ssh://git@bitbucket:7999/pip/pipelinelibrary.git',credentialsId: 'my-private-key'])

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
        stage ('cleaning workspace'){
            steps{
                script{
                    checkoutScm("ospatchingpipeline")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I am not sure whether I need to compile this code before uploading it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question. When you want to put things in `code markdown`,  you should indent it by 4 spaces. But, if you want things as normal text, it should not be indented. All in all, your question looks like it has the relevant information for potential answerers. If you have more information to add, like what you've tried to solve it, you can [edit] that into your question.

Comment: What files and folders is your source code in?

Comment: My class code is under src/main/java/org/com/**/git.groovy. Supporting Function is under root of project inside /vars/scmcheckout.groovy and finally the Jenkins code is in Jenkinsfile in the root of the project.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you are using a function (accessing objects of a class that you are importing) which doesn't implement ***Serializable*** interface.

When we had this problem due to the following function:

```
@NonCPS
private static boolean isDebugOn (ParamType param1) { ...
```

Removing `static` and Changing that to got rid of this error:

```
@NonCPS
private boolean isDebugOn (ParamType param1) { ...
```

It seems like it was a combination of `@NonCPS` and `static` that resulted in that error.

The @NonCPS annotation is useful when you have methods which use objects which aren't serializable. Normally, all objects that you create in your pipeline script must be serializable (the reason for this is that Jenkins must be able to serialize the state of the script so that it can be paused and stored on disk).

When you put @NonCPS on a method, Jenkins will execute the entire method in one go without the ability to pause. Also, you're not allowed to reference any pipeline steps or CPS transformed methods from within an @NonCPS annotated method. [More information about this can be found here.](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/README.md#technical-design)